# Where to keep site-wide counters, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Newb developer.   Need to put some counters on the site that counts the number of times certain songs are played.   It's related to the Song model, but doesn't have to be, and not of any one song instance.   Just wondering where I put a counter that acts like a constant?

```
if Subscription.where("band_id = ? and fan_id = ?", @band.id, @fan.id).any? && @fan.donating 
      @song.total_sub_donate_plays += 1
      @song.total_month_sub_donate_plays += 1

      site_wide.counter_total +=1
      site_wide.counter_total_month += 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have memcached/redis setup then use the `Rails.cache`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-increment

something like:

```
if Subscription.where("band_id = ? and fan_id = ?", @band.id, @fan.id).any? && @fan.donating 
  @song.total_sub_donate_plays += 1
  @song.total_month_sub_donate_plays += 1

  Rails.cache.increment("stats/counters/total")
  Rails.cache.increment("stats/counters/#{Date.current.strftime("%Y/%m")}", {expires_in: 40.days})
end
```

then later you can:

```
Rails.cache.read("stats/counters/total")
Rails.cache.read("stats/counters/#{Date.current.strftime("%Y/%m")}")
```

**Another option** is to create aggregate data tables. this will let you have more control in the long run.

something like:

```
class DailySongData
  # event_date: date,
  # sub_count:integer
  # listing_count:integer
end
```

this will help organize your data for future learning

Comment: I appreciate that man, although both answers are above me.   In the aggregate data table example, do you mean make an instance of an unrelated model that has an attribute i could use as a counter?

Comment: Yes for the aggregate data table example, create a new table/model and reference your song.